# How do I find typings for actions-on-google for Visual Studio Code

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write my function to fulfil requests from api.ai. I'm new to javascript and would like to have code documentation and help in the IDE when using command completion.

In the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense) of the Visual Studio Code, it mentions 'typings'. I don't know how to find the typings for the actions-on-google package / library.

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

Typings usually have the same name as the package that they are supporting, prefixed with `@types/`. In case of the Actions on Google SDK, the types can be installed using `npm install @types/actions-on-google`. This should enable autocomplete for Actions on Google on your project.

Typing are particularly useful if you are using TypeScript in your project, but even with a JavaScript-only project you should get some autocomplete information in Visual Studio Code.